# Getting context for SharedPreferences in a method

Tags: java, android, methods, android-studio, sharedpreferences

So I have a pdf plugin in my app, an it uses a public class SimpleDocumentReader. It's just a class, not an activity. I have a method where you can change the page of the document when it has finished loading:

```
@Override    
public void onLoadFinish(DocumentState.OPEN state) {
    if (state == OPEN.SUCCESS) {
    SharedPreferences pref= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences();
                String page = pref.getString("example_list","");
                goToPage(Integer.parseInt(page));
       }
    }
```

As you can see, I want to access the defaultsharedpreferences, where a string is stored with which I can change the page. The problem is, in tha brackets of getDeaultSharedPreferences(); I need the context. I have tried several things already:

getApplicationContext() (didn't work),

getActivity() also pretty stupid.

Also tried to make the method receive the context like this:

```
public void onLoadFinish(DocumentState.OPEN state, Context context) {

// line for getting sharedpreferences Context:
SharedPreferences pref= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
}
```

But it throws several errors:
First, the @Override isn't working because

> method does not override method from its superclass

Second error is at the top, the class itself:

```
public class SimpleDocumentReader implements ReaderListener {}
```

Throws this error:

Class "SimpleDocumentReader" must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onLoadFinish(OPEN)' in ReaderListener.

What does that mean?

EDIT: Here's how the SimpleDocumentReader class is being initiated:

First, creating a SimpleViewer with a SimpleReaderFactory in my Activity:

```
SimpleDocumentReader v = SimpleReaderFactory.createSimpleViewer(this, null);
v.openUrl("myurl", "mypassword");
```

Second, the SimpleReaderFactory:

```
public class SimpleReaderFactory {

    /**
     * Creates and returns a PDF viewer used for viewing, reading, and
     * navigating PDF document
     * 
     * @param act
     *            The activity of the current application.
     * @param listener
     *            The SimpleDocumentViewerListener instance.
     * 
     * @return SimpleDocumentViewer The default PDF document viewer instance
     */
    public static SimpleDocumentReader createSimpleViewer(Activity act,
            SimpleDocumentReaderListener listener) {

        SimpleDocumentReader viewer = new SimpleDocumentReader(act);
        viewer.setListener(listener);


        return viewer;
    }
}
```

And, at last, my SimpleDocumentReader:

```
    public class SimpleDocumentReader implements ReaderListener {
    // a lot of stuff here, I will post the important snippets of code:
    public void onLoadFinish(DocumentState.OPEN state) {
    if (state == OPEN.SUCCESS) {
                mControlView.init(mAct);

                RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(mAct);
                layout.addView(mReaderView);
                layout.addView(mControlView);

                mAct.setContentView(layout);

                CoordConverter.initCoordConverter(mAct, mReaderView);
                SharedPreferences pref= 
//my attempts at getting the defaultsharedpreferences
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences();
                String hour = pref.getString("example_list","");
                goToPage(Integer.parseInt(hour));
            }
}
```

Comment: where you are implementing `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks`  interface  ?

Comment: I haven't found that interface anywhere in my code (project search), but I could paste the whole code of the SimpleDocumentReader class if you want me to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does that mean?

Just what it says. `ReaderListener` requires you to have an `onLoadFinish()` with the signature `public void onLoadFinish(DocumentState.OPEN state)`, apparently.

With regards to your overall problem, pass the `SharedPreferences` into the constructor of `SimpleDocumentReader`, which holds onto it in a data member and uses it in `onLoadFinish()`.

Comment: The interesting thing is, I have a method in my ReaderListener interface: `void onLoadFinish(DocumentState.OPEN state);`

Comment: @just_deko: "I have a method in my ReaderListener interface" -- correct. I mentioned this in the first paragraph of my answer.

Comment: So, passing the sharedpreferences into the constructor means this: create "private final SharedPreferences sharedprefs; then use that in the method?

Comment: @just_deko: I am not certain that `final` will work there. But add a constructor to `SimpleDocumentReader` that takes a `SharedPreferences` as a parameter. In that constructor, assign that `SharedPreferences` to your `sharedprefs` data member. Elsewhere, refer to `sharedprefs` when you need the `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: by constructor you mean onCreate?

Comment: @just_deko: By "constructor", I mean "constructor". According to you, "It's just a class, not an activity", and so a constructor is a perfectly reasonable thing to add. You are welcome to use some other sort of setter method if you prefer, though I do not know what the advantage of that would be.

Comment: sorry for my stupidity, but HOW do I pass the parameter through the constructor?

Comment: @just_deko: Declare your constructor (e.g., `public SimpleDocumentReader(SharedPreferences p) { ... }`). Then pass the `SharedPreferences` when you create your `SimpleDocumentReader` instance (e.g., `new SimpleDocumentReader(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(...))`, where `...` is a `Context`, such as your `Activity`).

Comment: "such as your Activity" what activity? the problem is, this is a class, not an activity, where should I get the content from?

Comment: @just_deko: Something is creating an instance of your `SimpleDocumentReader`. I have no idea what it is. However, *everything* in Android starts with a `Context` somewhere. For example, if `SimpleDocumentReader` is being created in support of an `Activity`, then *somewhere* the `Activity` is triggering a series of calls that eventually results in you creating an instance of `SimpleDocumentReader`. You need to arrange to get a `SharedPreferences` down that series of calls.

Comment: Look at my edit please. Does that mean I have somehow to pass the sharedpreference through the simplereaderfactory to the simpledocumentreader?

Comment: @just_deko: Given the fact that you're already passing the `Activity` into the `SimpleDocumentReader`, just use it in your `SimpleDocumentReader` constructor to get your `SharedPreferences`. Remember: an `Activity` is a `Context`.

Comment: soo, what should I write instead of these three dots? getActivity()? My activity name with ()?

Comment: @just_deko: "what should I write instead of these three dots?" -- I have no idea, as I don't have enough of your code. Your posted listing for `SimpleDocumentReader` is incomplete, as it does not show the constructor, but your `createSimpleViewer()` method shows that you are calling one. In that constructor, you have a parameter, of data type `Activity`. Your parameter is named something, such as `act`. *That* is your `Activity`. *That* is a `Context`. Pass that object into `getDefaultSharedPreferences()`.

Comment: do you mean this? `public SimpleDocumentReader(Activity act) {
  mAct = act;
  mReaderView = new ReaderView(mAct);
  mReaderView.setReaderListener(this);

  mControlView = (SimpleReaderControlView) SimpleReaderControlView
    .inflate(mAct, R.layout.simple_reader_control, null);
  mControlView.createUILayout(mReaderView);
 }`

Comment: @just_deko: Yes, that is a constructor. Your `Activity` parameter is named `act`. Now, as it turns out, you are holding onto the `Activity` itself in a data member named `mAct`. In which case, all of this hassle could have been avoided -- just pass `mAct` into the `getDefaultSharedPreferences()` back in your very first code snippet in this question.

Comment: well... now I feel stupid. But still, a BIG thank you for staying with me and helping me out for so long!